# Nginx serve static content behind authenticated page

Tags: nginx, server, static-content

I have created a directory call library, that requires authentication to access.  Upon completing authentication I would like to list all files in library for the user.  I have tried autoindex to no avail, and most material I am finding doesn't cover whether or not the authentication will affect anything.

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then as
            # directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location include
            # /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /website {

    }

    location /library {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `location /library` block will impose the requirement of basic authentication and serve the same static files in `/usr/share/nginx/html/library` to all users who can successfully authenticate.  In short, all users who successfully auth will see the same files in your current config.

To serve *different* static files to *different* users, consider that Basic authentication will set the `$remote_user` variable (see [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_user)) which you can utilise to make your configuration dynamic.

For instance, if you wanted to serve a different folder for each user ID (at the same `/library` URL), you'd use a block like:

```
location /library {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/$remote_user/;
}
```

assuming your folders are named with the ID of your users and located at that path.

If a user fails the basic auth, they'll be shown a 403 Forbidden error, which you can handle using the `error_page` directive to show something more useful than just a basic error.  Likewise, if a user can successfully auth and a corresponding folder doesn't exist, they'll see a 404, which you could again handle with an `error_page` directive.